# Is it possible to use redux-form, connect and withRouter?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am building a login form using redux-form, connect and router (withRouter) but im really confused how to export the component using all the three:

```
SignUp = connect(
 mapStateToProps,
 mapDispatchToProps
)(SignUp);

export default withRouter(
 reduxForm({
  form: "registerForm", // a unique identifier for this form
  validate
 })(SignUp)
);
```

and the above code is not working because the props are undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
handleFormSubmit
src/containers/Auth/SignUp.js:43

```
  40 | 
  41 | handleFormSubmit(formValues) {
  42 |   console.log(formValues);
  43 |   this.props.onAuth(formValues);
     | ^  44 | }
  45 | render() {
  46 |   const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = 
       this.props;
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the full error message?

Comment: error message has been added to the post

Comment: show the `SignUp` component. You really need to write this `handleFormSubmit(formValues) {` as `handleFormSubmit = (formValues) => {` to get rid of `this` error, or bind the method inside the `constructor` function.

Comment: yeah i forgot the thing with "this". thank you so much for the quick answer and help